# Не понимаю как создать скрипт начисления процентов?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Ребята помогите, пожалуйста. Я совсем не понимаю как мне это сделать. Сайт на wordpress. Установлены плагины для платного доступа и млм Ultimate Membership Pro и Ultimate Affiliate Pro. Они между собой связаны. Человек при регистрации вносит какую-то плату (зависит от плана подписки) и внесённые средства должны получать процент в зависимости от суммы оплаты. 
Поставили задачу: Есть 3 плана подписки
1) Человек внес сумму например 10000 и с этого момента ему каждый месяц должно на счет капать по 25% от этой суммы в течении 6 месяцев причем в течении каждого месяца эти проценты (25% от 10000 = 2500) должны поступать равными частями каждый день (2500/колличество дней).
2) Человек внес сумму например 100000 и с этого момента ему каждый месяц должно на счет капать по 40% от этой суммы в течении 9 месяцев причем в течении каждого месяца эти проценты (40% от 100000 = 40000) должны поступать равными частями каждый день (40000/колличество дней).
3) Человек внес сумму например 1000000 и с этого момента ему каждый месяц должно на счет капать по 60% от этой суммы в течении 9 месяцев причем в течении каждого месяца эти проценты (60% от 1000000 = 600000) должны поступать равными частями каждый день (600000/колличество дней).

Также надо чтобы все эти процентные изменения человек видел в своём личном кабинете. (С этим я справлюсь сама)

Простите меня, я ещё глупая и только начинаю всё изучать, а тут сразу же такая задача. Заранее спасибо.

Как я вижу решение данной проблемы:
У каждого плана есть свой ID в базе данных. У каждого плана есть своя стоимость. При выборе какого либо плана пользователь получает определённый ранг или что-то такое. У каждого ранга есть свой ID в базе. Отталкиваясь от этого можно предположить, что если пользователь получил ранг с, например, ID 4, то он внёс 10000 и с этого момента начинается отсчёт 6 месяцев и начисление процентов.
Т.е. с помощью, возможно, php? мы можем узнать в базе у кого ранг с ID=4 и статус 1 (активирован) и присвоить ему определённый скрипт расчёта процентов.

```html
 <?php
/*Скрипт для 10000*/
mysql_query($query);
/* Отбираем из базы нужный ранг */
$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_ihc_user_levels WHERE level_id = \\\"4\\\" AND status != '0'";
/* Присваиваем level_id который равен 4 значение суммы (т.е. level_id="4" = 10000?) */
/* С даты из таблицы wp_ihc_user_levels и столбца start_time до даты в 
столбце expire_time начислять проценты к 10000 */


$row = ['start_time'];
$row = ['expire_time'];
/* Дата */
$row['start_time'] = strtotime($row['start_time']);
$row['expire_time'] = strtotime($row['expire_time']);
/* Сумма */
$amount = 10000; 
/* Даты начала и окончания */
$start = strtotime('start_time');
$end = strtotime('expire_time');
/* вычисляем количество месяцев (не знаю надо ли это делать если заранее известно их количество) */
$month = idate('m', $end) - idate('m', $start);
/* Начисляем процент */
$amountWithPct = $amount + 25 * $month;
/* Выводим результат */
printf(
    "%s Было %s Стало $%.2F", date('d.m.Y', $row['start_time']), $amountWithPct); 
?>
```

Так как я пробую написать у меня не получается вычислить количество месяцев от даты окончания до даты начала начисления процентов + не работает само начисление. Я прекрасно понимаю, что есть ошибки, но пока мне не хватает знаний.

Изучая всё подряд я дошла до такого варианта, но он всё равно не работает так как надо.

```html
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//Скрипт для 10000
require_once 'connection.php'; // подключаем скрипт
// подключаемся к серверу
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database) 
    or die("Ошибка подключения к базе" . mysqli_error($link));
mysqli_query($query);

$res = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `wp_ihc_user_levels` WHERE `level_id`= 1 AND `status` != 0") or die("Ошибка выборки" . mysqli_error($link));
if($res) { //если запрос успешный
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
  $start = ['start_time'];
  $end = ['expire_time'];
/* Дата */
  $start['start_time'] = strtotime($start['start_time']);
  $end['expire_time'] = strtotime($end['expire_time']);
/* Даты начала и окончания */
  $start = strtotime('start_time');
  $end = strtotime('expire_time');
$now = time(); // текущее время (метка времени)
$reg_date = strtotime($start['start_time']); // какая-то дата в строке
$datediff = $now - $reg_date; // получаем разность дат (в секундах)


/* Начисляем процент */
   $amount = 10000; 
   $proc = 25; //Процентов за всё время
         $proc_d =25/$datediff; //Процентов в день
   $proc = $amount/100*$proc; // высчитываем процент от числа
   $proc_d = $amount/100*$proc_d; // высчитываем процент в день от числа
   $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $proc; // суммируем число с процентами от этого числа
   $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $proc_d; // суммируем число с процентами в день от этого числа
   round ($amountWithPct_all); // округляем
   round ($amountWithPct_d); // округляем
 {
        //выводим как нам надо
   echo "ДАТА НАЧАЛА:<br><br>";
echo date("d.m.Y h:m:s",strtotime($start)),'<br><br>';
   echo "ДАТА ОКОНЧАНИЯ:<br><br>";
echo date('d.m.Y h:m:s',strtotime($end)),'<br><br>';
  echo "Прошло дней:<br><br>";
  echo floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24)),'<br><br>'; // вычисляем количество дней из разности дат
  echo "Сумма на данный момент: $amountWithPct_d<br><br>";
  echo "Итоговая сумма: $amountWithPct_all<br><br>";
  

    }
}

    mysqli_free_result($res); //очищаем занятую память - она уже не нужна

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Даты почему-то всегда выводятся такие 1970-01-01, соответственно сумма с процентами на данный момент выводится странная.
Вот так выглядит результат:
ДАТА НАЧАЛА:

01.01.1970 03:01:00

ДАТА ОКОНЧАНИЯ:

01.01.1970 03:01:00

Прошло дней:

18113

Сумма на данный момент: (10000.000001597),'

'Итоговая сумма: (12500),'

'
Где ошибки не пойму. Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Вот так выглядит таблица в БД.
[image: БД]

UPD:  Кусок с обращением в пустоту, предложенный DaemonHK, исправила. Больше такого не вижу. Пожалуйста, ткните носом в ошибки. Я уже почти отчаялась.

```html
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require_once 'connection.php';
  $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
  if (!$link) {
    echo 'Не могу соединиться с БД. Код ошибки: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ', ошибка: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
  }

  $sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `user_id`, `level_id`, `start_time`, `expire_time`, `status` FROM `wp_ihc_user_levels` WHERE `level_id`=1');
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $start=($result['start_time']);
    $end=($result['expire_time']);
    $level=($result['level_id']);
    $user_id=($result['user_id']);
    $status=($result['status']);
    $now = time();
    $datediff = date('d.m.Y') - date("d.m.Y", strtotime($result['start_time']));
   $amount = 10000; 
   $proc = 25;
     $proc_d =0.25*$datediff;
   $proc = $amount/100*$proc;
   $proc_d = $amount/100*$proc_d;
   $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $proc;
   $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $proc_d;
   round ($amountWithPct_all);
   round ($amountWithPct_d);

    echo "Дата начала: {$start}<br>";
   echo "Дата окончания:  {$end}<br>";
   echo "Прошло дней: {$datediff}<br>";
   echo "Внесено: {$amount} ₽<br>";
  echo "Заработано на данный момент: $proc_d ₽<br><br>";
  echo "Cумма на конец периода: $amountWithPct_all ₽<br><br>";
  }

?>
```

Вот так стало работать. Выводит правильные даты и правильно считает. Правда выводит всех пользователей с level_id=1. Но и это уже неплохо. Всем спасибо. Вопрос можно закрывать.

Comment: Приведите попытки самостоятельного решения задачи (пусть и неудачные). И напишите, что конкретно взывало затруднения.

Comment: Извините. Добавила что смогла.

Comment: Для начала вот это неправильно - $reg_date = strtotime(['start_time']); судя по всему должно быть $reg_date = strtotime($start['start_time']); Ну и так везде по коду, вы вместо обращения к массивам обращаетесь в пустоту.

Comment: А в процентах точно нет ошибки? Меня как-то смущает, что вы получаете 10,000 а отдаете 15,000 )) Может это уже вопрос к египтологам)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
require_once 'connection.php';
  $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
  if (!$link) {
    echo 'Не могу соединиться с БД. Код ошибки: ' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ', ошибка: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
  }

  $sql = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT `user_id`, `level_id`, `start_time`, `expire_time`, `status` FROM `wp_ihc_user_levels` WHERE `level_id`=1');
  while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $start=($result['start_time']);
    $end=($result['expire_time']);
    $level=($result['level_id']);
    $user_id=($result['user_id']);
    $status=($result['status']);
    $now = time();
    $datediff = date('d.m.Y') - date("d.m.Y", strtotime($result['start_time']));
   $amount = 10000; 
   $proc = 25;
     $proc_d =0.25*$datediff;
   $proc = $amount/100*$proc;
   $proc_d = $amount/100*$proc_d;
   $amountWithPct_all = $amount + $proc;
   $amountWithPct_d = $amount + $proc_d;
   round ($amountWithPct_all);
   round ($amountWithPct_d);

    echo "Дата начала: {$start}<br>";
   echo "Дата окончания:  {$end}<br>";
   echo "Прошло дней: {$datediff}<br>";
   echo "Внесено: {$amount} ₽<br>";
  echo "Заработано на данный момент: $proc_d ₽<br><br>";
  echo "Cумма на конец периода: $amountWithPct_all ₽<br><br>";
  }

?>
```

Вот так стало работать. Выводит правильные даты и правильно считает. Правда выводит всех пользователей с level_id=1. Но и это уже неплохо. Всем спасибо. Вопрос можно закрывать.